Standardizing necessary before Gower's distance?
I am unsure whether I should standardize my data material (numerical data with different scales) before performing Gower's distance calculation to obtain Gower's distance matrix.
If I understood the Gower's distance correctly, Gower's uses range-normalized Manhattan distance and dice similarity. Therefore a standardization before applying Gower's is unecessary, redundant and might lead to information loss?
What are your thought on this?

Your understanding is correct. The standardization of numerical features is redundant. Standardization is an affine transformation, so the relative value differences will remain the same; the subtraction of the mean (i.e. shift) will affect nothing because it cancels out immediately and the division with the standard deviation (i.e. scaling) will also affect nothing because we normalise by the range.
Here is a quick example in R too:
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(333)
N <- 1001; 
x <- rt(n=N, df=1, ncp=90) # Creates data from a non-centred t-distribution
x_stnd <- (x-mean(x))/sd(x)

(x[1]-x[2])/(max(x)- min(x))
# [1] 0.00117245
(x_stnd[1]-x_stnd[2])/(max(x_stnd)- min(x_stnd))
# [1] 0.00117245

